# str_replace inline script code from html in php not working

Tags: php, javascript, html

I have a html page stored in the mysql database. I get the html from the database and try to replace some of the inline javascript code from the html content. I tried using `str_replace()` but it does not replace the inline javascript code. I can replace other html content like divs but not inline javascript code.

How can I do find and replace the inline javascript code?

Comment: Can you show us the things you have already tried?

Comment: How are you replacing the divs?  What's an example of the inline javascript?

Comment: $stripped_html  = str_replace('<div id="footer">','<div id="footer" style="color:#CCCCCC">',$stripped_html); this is how i replace div content. This is what i mean by inline js : <script type="text/javascript">var hello = "Hi i am peter"; alert(hello); </script> So if i use $stripped_html  = str_replace('var hello = "Hi i am peter"','var hello = "Hello Users"',$stripped_html); it does not replace var hello it remains the same.

Answer (score 1):

PHP should be seeing the entire HTML page as a big string, so in theory, it should be able to alter JS and HTML alike.  Is it possible the string still has slashes, and your str_replace can't find the search criteria due to the slashes?

Try printing the entirety of the string to the screen to make sure, and if it does still have slashes, use a stripslashes($string) call to get rid of them.

Comment: If i echo the html it shows the html properly in the browser. I used stripslases but still it does not find and replace the javascript code. I tried replacing divs and plaintext it gets replaced only inline javascript does not get replaced.

Answer (score 0):

You probably want to use a DOM parser to handle your webpage as a DOM structure, not a serialised string of HTML (where things like string replacement and regular expressions can be troublesome).

Comment: I have tried using simplehtmldom. But i dont know how to find and replace the inline javascript. i used $dom->find('script'); but if i try to find the nodevalue $script->nodeValue; it does not get the inline javascript. How can i get the inline javascript and then replace it using simplehtmldom??